# Why this code is printing "YES" infinite number of times while it should have printed "NO" one time

Tags: c++, for-loop

for s="0" and k=20 this code is printing YES infinite number of times but the for loop condition (0<=1-20) is not true. it should print NO. Please help me.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int k;
    cin>>k;
    for(int i=0;i<=s.size()-k;++i){
        cout<<"YES"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it does not print infinite times, just a lot of times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is:  unsigned integer underflow.

To see it more clearly, let's assign the values to variables of type `size_t` (which is the type that `s.size()` returns):

```
const size_t ssize = s.size();
const size_t ssize_minus_k = ssize-k;
cout << "ssize=" << ssize << " ssize_minus_k=" << ssize_minus_k << endl;
for(int i=0;i<=ssize_minus_k;++i){
    cout<<"YES"<<endl;
}
```

.... with the above lines, the output of the program looks like this:

```
$ ./a.out 
0
20
ssize=1 ssize_minus_k=18446744073709551597
YES
YES
[...]
```

Now to fix the problem, let's change the type of our variables from `size_t` to `ssize_t` (note the extra `s`, meaning "signed"):

```
const ssize_t ssize = s.size();
const ssize_t ssize_minus_k = ssize-k;
cout << "ssize=" << ssize << " ssize_minus_k=" << ssize_minus_k << endl;
for(int i=0;i<=ssize_minus_k;++i){
    cout<<"YES"<<endl;
}
```

.... and now we get behavior more like what we were expecting:

```
$ ./a.out 
0
20
ssize=1 ssize_minus_k=-19
NO
```

Comment: why const ssize_t ssize_minus_k = -19 while const size_t ssize_minus_k =18446744073709551597. Can you tell me the reason? why does the behavior of i<s.size()-k is different while i<s.size() works fine? what is the problem with size_t data type?

Comment: @suthar0 It's not signed. Therefore, it can't store negative numbers and instead of going to -1 goes to it's maximal value. `i<s.size()` is never in the negative areas and thus works.

Comment: @Aziuth got it. Thanks for solving my doubt.